# Using transparent on white and black image, makes the transparency inverted

Tags: imagemagick, transparency, imagemagick-convert

I'm having a missue with a convertion.

Using a simple QR code with a white background and a black QR code, I wan't to have ImageMagick to make the white color transparent.

To do so, I tried this:

```
/usr/bin/convert ./qr_original.png -transparent white ./qr_transparent.png
```

This convert command makes the black color transparent but preserves the white background.

**But** trying with a QR code with a background and a red/green/blue/whatever QR code, the convert command works fine - the red/green/blue/whatever QR code is preserved and the white background gets transparent.

How come? And how can I make this work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works for me. Maybe update your imagemagick?

Otherwise try this:

```
exec("convert ./qr_original.png -channel matte -fuzz 50%% -fill transparent -opaque white ./qr_transparent.png");
```

Comment: You're right - my imagemagick installation is out of date, which apparently is the problem.

Comment: You should use -fuzz anyways to get a better result